# Embed LateX file to HTML

Tags: html, latex, embed

I am looking for a way to load a LateX file to HTML. I found several questions about that but most of them are talking about for adding LateX equations to HTML or to convert LateX to HTML or to add HTML to Latex.

I am looking for something different, I have a LateX file and I would like to embed that to my HTML file.

If you can think it like a PDF, I can embed a PDF to my HTML like that:

```
<embed src="somepdf.pdf" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/readstep2.html">
```

Is something equivalant for  LateX files?

Comment: AFAIK: no. There are specific extensions for some browsers but IMO nothing you can rely on.

Comment: So only via an API right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, it's still not clear to me if you want to embed in html your `.pdf` file or your `.tex` file, but this does not really matter. Copy and paste the following:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{PRIMES is in P}
\author{Not Me}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Hello.

\end{document}
```

into the blank file `test.tex`, then compile it to produce `test.pdf`. Now, provided that `test.tex`, `test.pdf` and the following html are in the same folder, this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>iframe tag</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="test.tex" width="275" height="250"></iframe>
<iframe src="test.pdf" width="400" height="566"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

should make the job. It works on Firefox, Chrome and Opera (on Windows 7). Instead - but this doesn't surprise me... - MS Internet Explorer shows the source file only if you save it as `.txt` (not `.tex`).

More about `iframe` tag:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-iframe-element